# shruti font is not working proper

Tags: android

i need to print gujrati font fron string.xml file with Shruti.ttf font in textview but it is not printing right specially in case of vowels

e.g i want to print **પિતા:**

and in textview it find -->

[image]

Comment: Android doesn't support indic fonts.. using typeface will not help it. It parses the contents badly. Just switching it over in the wrong place. I had the same problem with tamil. Still couldn't get a clean solution on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do same thing using local. for more information you may prefer  [this link](http://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

your phone's rom doesn't support the character/font

Comment: is there any soultion for this ? ,because it is meaning less to use this

Answer (score 0):

Support for Indic languages was first introduced in ICS, and fully implemented in Jellybean. You'll have hard time trying do it on older devices, you need the device to be rooted in able to do that.

[reference 1](http://microblog.ravidreams.net/android-ics-support-for-tamil-indic-languages/)

For Rooted phone, here is the method:

1.Download Indian font from this link http://www.mediafire.com/?6isti7ew908mwiy and copy to your SD Card
2. Download ES File Explorer
3. In ES file Explorer go to Settings > Path settings put a check mark in “Up to Root”  move a little below you will find “root settings” In it enable “root Explorer”(you will get a popup asking for root permission just click OK in it) also enable “Mount File system” under “root settings”. 
4. Delete “DroidSansFallback.ttf” present in /system/fonts/ and copy the new(the one you have downloaded) “DroidSansFallback.ttf” from your SD card to /system/fonts/ 
5. After copying long press over “DroidSansFallback.ttf” select “properties”  permissions must be “rw- r-- r-- “ , If not change the same.
6. Now reboot the phone and you can enjoy Enjoy Indian fonts